# MySQL: Performance on user settings stored in one row (flat) versus multiple rows (key-value pairs)

Tags: mysql, sql, performance

Which of the following two queries would be faster? more performant?

### Setup A

`userSetting` table just includes all parameters as columns

```
userSettingId | userId | marketingEmail | weeklyEmail | pushNotifications
--------------------------------------------------------------------
    120       |    1   |        1       |       1     |          0
```

```
select userSetting.userId, user.email
from userSetting
    INNER JOIN user ON userSetting.userId = user.userId
where marketingNotifEmail = 1;
```

or

### Setup B

`userBoolSetting` table with keeps key/value pairs, where the value is a boolean, 0 or 1

```
userBoolSettingId | userId |   description        |       value
-----------------------------------------------------------------
    121           |    1   |   marketingEmail     |         1
    122           |    1   |   weeklyEmail        |         1
    123           |    1   |   pushNotifications  |         0
```

```
select userBoolSetting.userId, user.email
from userBoolSetting
    INNER JOIN user ON userBoolSetting.userId = user.userId
where notificationType = 'marketingEmail'
  AND isEnabled = 1;
```

Also, for the sake of clarity, I'd be looking at the performance at a bit larger table than these examples. Which query would be most performant for a larger data set, say 50-100 parameters, not just 3 as shown.

Comment: 1 - 10 -100 data are normally not a performance problema.. 10.000 100.000 could create some problems easily solved by index ...

Comment: Why are you worrying about performance? Will you work with tens of gigabytes of data? If not, always use the approach that lets you obtain information **easily** and one that's readable, maintainable and extensible. Will you extend configuration options as the time goes by? If yes, then you need to alter the table every time you add one (or remove one). The query that performs the fastest is the one that does the least. That should not be your worry for the moment. Your worry should be to figure out how this configuration data model is supposed to work first.

Comment: The idea is for a notification service. Say notifications could possibly go out every 5 minutes. The system would have to check the user's preference to see if whether or not a notification should be sent. The performance case would be when there are many users that receive the same notification. I imagine it can be a bottleneck if you have to get all the users who have that particular notification setting on. 
Every time there is a notification to be dispatched to a group, I need to look up all the users that belong to the group and have that notification enabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As has been pointed out many times in this forum, splaying an array of things across columns is not good because it is unmaintainable, etc.

Performance of fetching a hundred rows is not bad.

Throwing them into a JSON string is another option.